# C1TrueDBGrid / How to programatically determine if a cell is readonly

Tags: winforms, componentone

Given instance of a C1TrueDBGrid and cell location (row and column indexes), how can I determine if the cell is editable or readonly?

Comment: If someone can create the C1TrueDBGrid tag it would be nice.

Comment: http://our.componentone.com/groups/winforms/true-dbgrid-for-winforms/forum/topic/how-to-programatically-determine-if-a-cell-is-readonly

Comment: enclose the code snippet where you are trying to edit a cell in a try catch block. Check the exception in Catch block and return if it is read only.

Answer (score 0):

The query has already been taken care of on the [C1Forums](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/how-to-programatically-determine-if-a-cell-is-readonly/).

Regards,
Mohita